# Can't get ResponseText value when request is failed on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I do model validation customly on server side by setting value to ResponseBody of response object and setting HttpStatusCode to BadRequest.

In local development over IIS Express, i can get that ResponseText value on client side but in Azure Websites that value is handled by Azure WebSites so it is changed. What i want to do is having full control when Http exception is happen on server side without manipulation of Azure Websites.

How can i do that ?

Comment: For this scenario (model validation) you shouldn't technically be returning HTTP 400 anyway. The technical definition is "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.", from http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html.

Comment: @TathamOddie In Web Api examples, they assign BadRequest code for request status if model validation is false.

Comment: A published specification document, vs. a sample app built by one person. I'll trust the spec. :)